# Can touch events be forwarded to an MKMapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I want to display a map view as a permanent background while other views are displayed on top of it (I'm going to set the alpha of the top view to something like 0.9 so the map is just faintly visible underneath) and at some points the map get revealed.

I have a container view which is layered on top of the map view and I would like to know if touch events that occur within the bounds of the container view can be passed to the map view so that it can be scrolled etc. Here's a sketch project showing an example of the architecture.[image]

[image]

(The Container view is on top of the bottom half of the map view, the container view and contained View Controller's view's alphas are both 0, so to the user the map is visible on the entire screen).

Its easy to forward the touch events occurring within the Contained View Controller's views or child view controllers to the Map Background View Controller.

If I do something like pass the touch event to the map view like this

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    MapBackgroundViewController *parent = (MapBackgroundViewController *) self.parentViewController;
    [parent.mapView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

then nothing happens.

Is there a way of passing the touch events to the map view such that it will scroll etc.?

Comment: can't you achieve this without using a seperate viewcontroller ontop of map backgroundviewcontroller ? (perhaps using a childview in mapbackgroundvc ...)

Comment: There's too much happening in the views and too many of them on top of the map that I need lots of view controllers to organize them all. The contained view controller is effectively the RVC for a whole hierarchy of other stuff. Trying to implement this all as separate views would be very messy and unorganized.

Comment: see what happens when you set the `userInteractionEnabled=NO` to those top views. if so you can work back from that point.

Comment: I'll try a few experiments with that. It looks like if I bring the map view to the foreground at run time and move it back as/when needed I can get it to scroll. So might be able to develop some of these ideas into something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

What I do is subclass `UIView` and override `hitTest:withEvent:` such that touches are passed through unless a subview is touched. Something like this:

```
@implementation PassthroughView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    return view == self ? nil : view;
}

@end
```

Then I assign this class to my container view and the contained view controller's main view in IB. So you can still interact with the content of the contained view controller, but touches on the container itself get passed through to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can pack your overlay views all into one container view, in which you then override [`-pointInside:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#jumpTo_100) to return `NO`:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return NO;
}
```

This will make the view effectively "untappable".

Alternatively you can also override [`-hitTest:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#jumpTo_89) to return `nil`.

Simply setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` won't work unfortunately, since the taps will still arrive in the view and be swallowed.